# Solve linear equation system $A'Ax=A'Bz$

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

For $A$ and $B$ known matrices which are not square matrices, I have the following equation sistem i would like to solve numerically
\begin{equation}
A'Ax=A'Bz
\end{equation}
I want to know which is a numerically stable and fast algorithm that can be used avoiding the computation of $A'A$ which is a full rank matrix. 
I know i can use Cholesky method if I compute $A'A$, but I guess i could get Cholesky descomposition from $A$ or may be something better.

Thanks a lot

Comment: A slow but numerically stable method would be to use the QR decomposition.

Comment: [Singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), see also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods)

Comment: QR fits my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are solving for $x$.

Apply the least squares algorithm to the problem $Ax = Bz$. This is the most efficient way.

*Numerical Recipes* recommends as follows:

> We need to warn you that the solution of a least-squares problem
>   directly from the normal equations is rather susceptible to roundoff
>   error. An alternative, and preferred, technique involves QR
>   decomposition

Comment: Interesting, Do i need any assumption over $A$ to do this? Do you know which would be the alternative technique?

Comment: @Manuel what do you mean by *alternative technique* - alternative to least squares or an alternative to QR decomposition implementation of least squares?

Comment: I missread the warning. I thought that QR descomposition was a different technique to solve the problem, not that It was the method to calculate least squares

Answer (score 0):

If $A'$ is invertible, your system becomes $Ax=Bz$. Then you can use Gauss-Jordan algorithm, or Gauss-Seidel iterative algorithm, if you want respectively an exact or approximated solution.

Comment: $A'$ is not a squared matrix

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read carefully. I will think about it.